# Using CGContextSetTextDrawingMode with setLineWidth property (drawRect function)

Tags: swift, uilabel, overriding, drawrect, func

How can I use "setLineWidth" and "setLineJoin" properties with CGContextSetTextDrawingMode in Swift?

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, CGTextDrawingMode.Stroke)

    context?setLineWidth(2)
    context.setLineJoin(CGLineJoin.Round)

}
```

Only properties (setLineWith and setLineJoin) are not working.
It worked one year ago. But now it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Swift 3

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.stroke)

    context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context?.setLineJoin(.round)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did update to latest version of swift. Now it is working!